# jQuery Div Scroll Down After Each Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that is serving as a chat, and depending on the users actions I append messages. I want it so, after each message is appended, the div will scroll down. However, it's not working 100%.

Here is the fiddle to check out: https://jsfiddle.net/mfj1ub8c/

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the delays/fadein/hide methods on each append, but they need to be there to give a certain effect that is needed.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `scrollDown` is being called before the element is actually shown (display: block) by `fadeIn`, so the scroll height hasn't changed yet. If you call `scrollDown` after `fadeIn` is complete, you'd miss the animation when the new content is off-screen. What you want to do is scroll when the element is displayed, but still transparent (opacity: 0). If you are on jQuery 1.8+ you can use [the start option](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-options).

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mfj1ub8c/2/

Also you are overshooting your scrollTop, which won't cause you problems here, but it should be the whole height minus the visible height.

> $('#chat').prop("scrollHeight") - $('#chat').height()

Answer (score 2):

Call `scrollDown` only when [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) is complete. You can use the complete callback parameter of fadeIn.

e.g.

```
.fadeIn(500, scrollDown))
```

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mfj1ub8c/1/